# Spherical parametric plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

How can I plot such a parametrized curve:

$r = 2\cos t + \sin t$

$\theta = t$

$\phi = \sin 10t$

where $0<t<\pi/2$.

In the documentation only has been discussed parametric plot in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Does `RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t] + Sin[t], t, Sin[10 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` give what you need?

Comment: I don't think so. The plot should be a curve.

Comment: ... or  `ParametricPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t] + Sin[t], t, Sin[10 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`?

Comment: I found in documentation that ParametricPlot3D treats the first three slots as x, y and z variables. But my problem is parametrized r, theta and phi.

Comment: related: [67261](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67261/5478)

Answer (score 11):

1. covert your spherical parametrized curve into cartesian parametrized curve with formulas:

$$\begin{cases}
x&=r\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
y&=r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
z&=r\cos\theta
\end{cases}$$

in *Mathematica* better use some function for this:

```
    ConvertToCartesianParametr[r_, theta_,phi_] :=
    {r*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi], *Sin[theta]*Sin[phi], r*Cos[theta]}
```

2. use `ParametricPlot3D` as mentioned by Alexei Boulbitch

   ```
   r = 2*Cos[t] + Sin[t];
   theta = t;
   phi = Sin[10*t];
   ParametricPlot3D[ConvertToCartesianParametr[r, theta, phi], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
   ```

Answer (score 11):

If you have version 9+ you can use:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian",{2 Cos[t]+Sin[t],t,Sin[10 t]}]],
    {t,0,Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is just the answer of @kguler, with a slight modification. Try this:

```
    ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[t] + Sin[t])*Sin[t]*
   Cos[Sin[10 t]], (2 + Cos[t] + Sin[t])*Sin[t]*
   Sin[Sin[10 t]], (2 + Cos[t] + Sin[t])*Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

A nice curve it is. 
Have fun!

Comment: If you have version 9+ you can use: `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[CoordinateTransform[ "Spherical" -> "Cartesian",{2 Cos[t]+Sin[t],t,Sin[10 t]}]],{t,0,Pi/2}]`