# Plot a parametric equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, coordinate-transformation

I'm looking for a way to plot this parametric equation on cylindrical coordinates.

```
r = e^t
theta = t+1
z = e^2t
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spherical parametric plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61059/spherical-parametric-plot)

Comment: Well, % /. "Spherical"->"Cylindrical".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created this function to convert from cylindrical to cartesian:

```
thing[r_, theta_, z_] := {r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], z}
```

Then use `ParametricPlot3D`

```
ParametricPlot3D[thing[Exp[t], t + 1, Exp[2 t]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: your answer was what i was looking for, I have no problem plotting parametric equations on spherical coordinates but somehow this eluded me. Thanks you very much