# plot of phase on cylinder

Tags: plotting

[image]

I have a data including the function theta as a function of x ranging from 0 to pi and the function theta ranges from -pi to pi or from 0 to 2pi:

I would like to plot this function something like winding number as the figure attached.
How can I plot this type of function using Mathematica?

Regards.

Comment: You can include any code you have written so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phase portrait on a cylinder](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/phase-portrait-on-a-cylinder)

Comment: @Kuba I'm not sure. This one isn't asking for an arbitrarily complicated graph projected onto a cylinder, but simply a polar plot extended along the third dimensions which allows for somewhat simpler solutions.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Right, vote retracted.

Comment: closely related: [Spherical parametric plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61059/5478)

Answer (score 6):

You can write a very simple elongated polar plot using `ParametricPlot3D` and cylindrical coordinates:

```
f[x_] := x^2
Show[
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], Glow@White, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {Pi, 0, 0}}, 1]},
     Axes -> True, Boxed -> False], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, -Cos[t], -Sin[t]} /. t -> f[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
]
```

[image]

I suppose the presentation could be improved a bit by also rendering the top and bottom "edge" of the cylinder and using an orthogonal instead of perspective projection, but this gets you your graph on the cylinder.

You can also avoid the manual conversion from cylindrical to Cartesian coordinates by using

```
Evaluate @ CoordinateTransform["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {1, f[x], x}]
```

inside the `ParametricPlot3D`, which probably makes for clearer code. But note that in this case the roles of the x and z axes are swapped, so you'll want to change the orientation of the `Cylinder` as well:

```
Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Pi}}, 1]
```

Comment: I have another question. I want to replace the weak-lightening solid line with the dashed lines when lines on the cylinder enter into the backside of cylinder. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @Lee [Like this?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/2305) Otherwise please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks! Although it looks much complicated, I will try it!